# Dynamic Range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm with some Checkboxes and TextFields and when I press on the "Insert" button the inputs are pasted in row 1 column A - 7.

I have the following problem:

After I press the button, I want to fill out the UserForm again and paste the data in row 2 and then 3, 4, 5, 6 and so on. Can someone tell me how I can jump dynamically to the next row and insert there the data?

My codesnippet for a checkbox is the following:

```
If UserForm1.eig_hand.Value = True Then
    Range("E3").Value = "Yes"
End If
```

This snippet will be executed after I press the "Insert button" and it would be very helpful, when I can close and reopen the Excel file and continue in the row where I closed the file. I know that I have a static expression in the Code snippet but I'm a completly beginner in VBA

Edit:

I found a solution for my problem.
I have a counter variable in a cell for example cell(5,1) and my code looks like this:

```
Dim counter_var As Integer
counter_var = Cells(5, 1)
If UserForm1.eig_hand.Value = True Then
Cells(counter_var, 4).Value = "Ja"
End If
If UserForm1.eig_kmu.Value = True Then
Cells(counter_var, 5).Value = "Ja"
End If
```

And at the end of my code i set the counter_var += 1.
Ty for all the replies :)

Comment: i suggest you add examples and snapshots to better explain what you're trying to do

Comment: Also provide some more code to this, to get help much more better then a dyanamic code. Thanks

Comment: Hey you 2. I have not more code. I'm a completly beginner in vba so i just use if else statements to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just:

```
Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value= "Yes"
```

But mine as well as your code has one significant weakness - they may give unexpected results when you switch between workbooks and worksheets. But it is answer for your question.

Comment: Hey ty for your answer :) I will try it. My idea was, that i have a counter cell for example A1 = 0 and every time i press on "Insert" the counter variable gets incremented. And the Range is the variable. I.e. in pseudo code:
counter_variable = 5
Range("H", counter_variable).... but i don't know how to write something like this. With this solution, i think i can save, close and reopen the file to continue with my work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub ButtonCode()
    Dim E2 As Range, n As Long

    Set E2 = Range("E2")

    If E2 = "" Then
        E2 = "yes"
    Else
        n = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("E2:E" & n) = "yes"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey ty for the reply. I found an answer. A very simple answer for me, a vba noob :) i'll post it

Comment: @NealMcBeal Good...............please update your original question with the best answer you have found.